# Suggestion for refactor wpf project

Tags: c#, design-patterns, wpf

I have done a WPF project and hope everyone can give suggestion for code refactor, especially for

UpdateErrorList() method within the MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
 private void UpdateErrorList()
    {
        char[] targetChar = new char[] { '(', ')' };

        errors.Clear();

        for (int count = 0; count < _classes.Count; count++)
        {
            foreach (var student in _classes[count]._Students)
            {
                if (_isDisplayGreen == true && _isDisplayYellow == true && _isDisplayRed == true)
                {
                    if (student.Value._Status == Status.YELLOW || student.Value._Status == Status.RED)
                    {
                        errors.Add(student.Value._Name.Split(targetChar)[1]);
                    }
                }
                else if (_isDisplayGreen == false && _isDisplayYellow == true && _isDisplayRed == true)
                {
                    if (student.Value._Status == Status.YELLOW || student.Value._Status == Status.RED)
                    {
                        errors.Add(student.Value._Name.Split(targetChar)[1]);
                    }
                }
                else if (_isDisplayGreen == false && _isDisplayYellow == false && _isDisplayRed == true)
                {
                    if (student.Value._Status == Status.RED)
                    {
                        errors.Add(student.Value._Name.Split(targetChar)[1]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ErrorStr = string.Join(", ", (from error in errors select error).ToArray<string>());
    }
```

[Download Project](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=233E2A690341BB1D!506&authkey=!AMk0_xfBS9L7nJ4&ithint=file%2Crar)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Code Review! I took a brief look at your code but it's pulling in all sorts of class-level members. Could you please include some more contextual code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd first find out which Statuses need to be displayed:

```
List<Status> requiredStatuses = new List<Status>();
if(_isDisplayYellow == true)
    requiredStatuses.Add(Status.YELLOW)
if(_isDisplayRed == true)
    requiredStatuses.Add(Status.RED)
```

And then use that list like this (note that I've also replaced you for loop with a foreach):

```
foreach (var class in _classes)
{
    foreach (var student in class._Students)
    {
        if(requiredStatuses.Contains(student.Value._Status))
           errors.Add(student.Value._Name.Split(targetChar)[1]);
    }
}
```

However, there's plenty of other things in this code that worry me:

- `class._Students` : `Students` shouldn't start with an underscore if it is a public property. Same for `Name` in `student.Value._Name`.
- `Status.YELLOW` : Yellow shouldn't be in all caps (and I hope `Status` is an enum).
- What is `errors` and why do you do `(from error in errors select error).ToArray<string>()` ? String.Join can handle IEnumerables since .NET 4. Why is errors a global field?
- Is you're using `student.Value._Name.Split(targetChar)[1]` this often, why not expose this as a read-only property on the Student class?
- `ErrorStr` is a bad name. Just call it `Error`, you already now it is a string because you're using visual Studio.
- Moreover, wouldn't it be better to have an `ObservableCollection<string> Errors` which contains the names of the students and then bind that to a Repeater or something like it instead of a comma separated string?

Comment: Hi BCdotNET, thanks for you reply. I have changed 1. all the property without underscore, 2. caps in Status enum(you are correct)

Comment: 3 and 4 still in progress, 5. already done and last the ObservableCollection will be removed